# Could not unzip uploaded file. Please check your file, then try to upload again Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

Im trying to create a lambda function from another lambda function with the library `boto3` and I'm having some issues, specially with the `code` part of the creation.

In `boto3` [Documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.create_function), it states that for code, we need something like this.

```
Code={
        'ZipFile': b'bytes',
        'S3Bucket': 'string',
        'S3Key': 'string',
        'S3ObjectVersion': 'string'
    }
```

Below that, it states the following according to the code area.

Code (dict) --
**[REQUIRED]**

The code for the function.

**ZipFile** (bytes) --
The base64-encoded contents of the deployment package. AWS SDK and AWS CLI clients handle the encoding for you.

**S3Bucket** (string) --
An Amazon S3 bucket in the same AWS Region as your function. The bucket can be in a different AWS account.

**S3Key** (string) --
The Amazon S3 key of the deployment package.

**S3ObjectVersion** (string) --
For versioned objects, the version of the deployment package object to use.

From I understand, I can create a bucket which contains the code (I dont need any custom dependencies so no deploy package). From that I can create the function (Clearly im wrong).

```
client.create_function(
        FunctionName = 'Test',
        Runtime = 'python3.7',
        Role = 'role',
        Handler = 'Test.lambda_handler',
        Code = {
            'S3Bucket': 'myBucketName',
            'S3Key': 'FunctionNameInsideBucket.py'
        }
    )
```

When I run the above code, I get `Could not unzip uploaded file. Please check your file, then try to upload again.`.

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong? Is creating a function from source code in a bucket possible or a zip file and deploy package is a must?

Comment: Please describe what issues/errors you are encountering.

Comment: Sorry!, edited the question

Comment: @Manuel please accept the correct answer to give credit where it's due.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't upload a single .py file via this method. You must upload the Lambda function as a .zip file.

Comment: Worked perfectly!